# Verification of exceeding numeric type limit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, numeric

Is there any way to recognize whether an unpredictable value would exceed the max value of a numeric type? In the following code the result of the if clause is always false and no exception is raised.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _Integer1, _Integer2: Integer;
begin
  _Integer1 := MaxInt;

  _Integer2 := _Integer1 + _Integer1;

  if _Integer2 > MaxInt then
  begin
    Caption := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    Caption := IntToStr(_Integer2); // -2
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `_Integer2 > MaxInt` will never return `True` because it is impossible. The value of an `Integer` cannot ever be greater than the greatest possible value of an `Integer`.

However, you can enable [overflow checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overflow_checking_(Delphi)):

```pascal
var
  x, y, z: Integer;
begin

  {$Q+}                         // enable overflow checking

  x := MaxInt div 2;
  y := MaxInt div 4;

  z := x + y;                   // fine

  ShowMessage(z.ToString);

  x := MaxInt div 2;
  y := 3 * (MaxInt div 4);

  try
    z := x + y;                 // exception
    ShowMessage(z.ToString);    // won't run
  except
    on EIntOverflow do
      ShowMessage('Integer overflow.');
  end;
```

Here I enable overflow checking locally using a compiler directive: `{$Q+}`. If you want to use overflow checking in a particular function or procedure, you can use this together with a resetter, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658575/282848) but opposite.

You can also turn it on for an entire project using **Project** > **Options** > **Delphi Compiler** > **Compiling** > **Runtime errors** > **Overflow checking**. Just remember that this setting is *per configuration* (for instance, debug vs. release).

Answer (score 2):

You can save the result in a larger integer type, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _Integer1: Integer;
  _Integer2: Int64;
begin
  _Integer1 := MaxInt;

  _Integer2 := Int64(_Integer1) + _Integer1;

  if _Integer2 > MaxInt then
  begin
    Caption := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    Caption := IntToStr(_Integer2);
  end;
end;
```

Or, you can calculate the available number space manually, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _Integer1, _Integer2: Integer;
begin
  _Integer1 := MaxInt;

  if (MaxInt - _Integer1) < _Integer1 then
  begin
    Caption := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    _Integer2 := _Integer1 + _Integer1;
    Caption := IntToStr(_Integer2);
  end;
end;
```

Or, you can enable Overflow Checking, as shown in Andreas' answer.